# Regular Expression: Span and ID dynamic

Tags: c#, regex

This regular expression in C# doesn't work:

```
 Regex regexSpan = new Regex("<span class=\"test\"  id=\"" + value + "\">"(.*?)</span>",
 RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I want to search the span with the ID that I indicate dynamically. The text inside the tag can be either.

Can somebody help me find the error in this regular expression?

Regards.

Comment: Show us example html to match for more clarity. Either way formatting points out that above code shouldn't even compile (notice red coloring ends before the end of regex itself due to extra quotation marks before (.*?)).

Comment: If it's C#, I don't think the quotes are escaped properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put an extra ending-quote mark after the first > sign.
The regex should look like:

```
"<span class=\"test\"  id=\"" + value + "\">(.*?)</span>"
```

Notice than in the HTML, the class attribute doesn't always come before the id attribute, so this code will only work in specific cases.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
\<span\s+class\s?=[^\,]+,\s*id\s?=[^\,]+\,?\s*value\s?=[^\>]+([^\<]*)\<\/span\>
```

match:

```
<span class="", id="", value=""></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex are not the one that were designed to parse XMLs. You should use `XML parser` and try with appropriate `xpath`.

[Manipulate XML data with XPath and XmlDocument](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C)

[How to query XML with an XPath expression by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333)